# Using the 'Mean' mergeRule with a spatial join

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join, field-mapping

I have two feature classes. The first is a point file, derived from a raster, with the values for slope of the terrain. The second is a shapefile of polygons. What I want to do is spatially join the points to polygons using the ONE_TO_ONE join option, and for each polygon contain an average value of the slope of all the points that are within the polygon.

The problem is when I execute the following code, the GRID_CODE field (slope values from the points shapefile) is empty for the output feature class.

```
import arcpy
print "\n\n************************\n"
slopes = r'C:\Users\slope_to_pt.shp'
polygons = r'C:\Users\polygons.shp'
outfc = r'C:\Users\slopeToPolygons'
print "Creating Field Map"

#create the field map
myMap = arcpy.FieldMappings()
myMap.addTable(polygons)
myMap.addTable(slopes)


fIndex = myMap.findFieldMapIndex("GRID_CODE")
print "GRID_CODE index is:", fIndex

#create new field map with the "GRID_CODE" field
NewFieldMap = myMap.getFieldMap(fIndex)

#set the merge rule
NewFieldMap.mergeRule = 'Mean'
print "merge rule is:", str(NewFieldMap.mergeRule)
myMap.replaceFieldMap(fIndex,NewFieldMap)
print "performing spatial join..."
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(polygons, slopes, slopeToPolygons, "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "", myMap, "CONTAINS")
```

Again, when I run this code the GRID_CODE entry for each polygon is null, when it should be the average of all the values of the points that are within the polygon. Whenever I run it with a "JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY" option, it populates the GRID_CODE field; however, I want to perform a ONE_TO_ONE join.

Additional Information: the datatype for the GRID_CODE field is 'double'

Any ideas on why it wouldn't populated the GRID_CODE field for each polygon with the averages from the points?

Comment: I'm surprised the spatial join execute as `slopeToPolygons` does not seem to be declared anywhere?

Comment: I've run pretty much your exact code (swapping in comparable datasets that I have on hand) and I'm getting the averaged value that you're looking for in my equivalent of the `GRID_CODE` field.  As @Hornybydd notes the variable `outfc` should be called `slopeToPolygons` or `outfc` should appear in the spatial join tool, and the file path that `outfc` points to needs a `.shp` at the end, but besides that the code seems to be sound.

Comment: @Hornbydd: in my actual code there is no discrepancy in terms of the spatial join excecute, I changed the names and filepaths when I posted the code here.

Comment: @msmi235 have you resolved this question? I have successfully field mapped a spatial join with a "SUM" merge rule recently.